# How to increase the range of BLE chip RN4871

Tags: antenna, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I have an RN4871 Bluetooth chip and integrated it with my micro. The chip is scanning for nearby BLE devices and reporting them to the host micro via UART. However, I see that the range of this chip is just 10 m. I could buy RN4870 and increase the range to 50m, but that's still not enough.

I see that the power output of the chip is 0dBm (1mW) and the max transmit power is 100mW (20dBm) for BLE 5.1. Apparently there is no way to increase this. Lame, I know.

So my only option is to find an antenna that has a higher gain compared to the built-in antenna (5dBm) of the chip and replace it with it. Can somebody back me up on my idea?

Also, is there a better way to increase the range of the chip?

Datasheet: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/RN4870-71-Bluetooth-Low-Energy-Module-Data-Sheet-DS50002489D.pdf

Comment: *Scanning* for BLE devices is a *passive* activity so what matters is your antenna and to a slight degree the RF quietness of your equipment overall (power supply noise, etc), not your transmit power output.

Comment: Also, the units of gain are dB, not dBm.  A figure in dBm is an expression of *power* in dB relative to a milliwatt.

Comment: Alright .. what parameters of the Antenna? Can't pick a random Antenna. If it's not Transmit power, then what parameters should I consider when I buy an Antenna to increase the range.

Comment: I have experience with bluetooth class 1 (100m) and homemade antenna "single wire" from UTP cable (L / 4) ~ 31mm. The antenna works well so  you can try.

Comment: Is it possible to use a surface mount Antenna? I found the following:
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/linx-technologies-inc/ANT-DB1-NSP250-T/343-ANT-DB1-NSP250-TCT-ND/10258688

Impedance is 50ohm. no matching circuit required
Max power is 5W and peak gain is 2.7dB. Should be longer range.